# print the name of the variable in a list without evaluation

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

```
a := az + 1
b := bz + 5
list := {a, b}
```

I'd like mathematica to print

```
a = az + 1
b = bz + 5
```

so basically it needs to first print the name of the variable in the list, followed by "=", and followed by the actual content of the variable.

**update (1):**

so here is something close to what I want

```
a := az + 1
b := bz + 5
list := {Hold@a, Hold@b}
Column[Table[Print[list[[i]], "=", ReleaseHold@list[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]]
```

outputs:

```
Hold[a]=1+az
Hold[b]=5+bz
```

However, I don't know how to get rid of `Hold[]`. I'm also hoping there is a more elegant way.

Comment: `HoldForm` works like `Hold` except that it isn't printed. Therefore I guess replacing `Hold` with `HoldForm` should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x_] := #[[1]] <> "=" <> #[[2]] &@ StringSplit[ToString@Definition@x, ":="]
```

Comment: I like the use of `Definition` which is not new to me but is nonetheless something that I don't usually consider +1.

Comment: this one is a little hard to understand. can you add more info? # is the argument of a pure function, <> is string joint. What does &@ mean?I can see it starts the pure function.

Comment: @kirill_igum The function **#[[1]] <> "=" <> #[[2]] &** takes it's argument from  the list **StringSplit[ToString@Definition@x, ":="]**

Comment: `StringReplace[ToString[Definition[x]], ":=" -> "="]` is simpler :)

Comment: @R.M yep. you are right!

Answer (score 6):

```
StringForm["`` = `` \n`` = ``", HoldForm[a], a, HoldForm[b], b]
```

or

```
  StringForm["`` = `` \n`` = ``", Defer[a], a, Defer[b], b]
```

both give

[image]

EDIT: To deal with the `az=1` issue noted by belisarius, i steal Andy's `OwnValues`-based approach with a slight variation:

```
  SetAttributes[prntHF, {HoldAll, Listable}];
  prntHF[sym_] := (OwnValues[sym] /. 
  {RuleDelayed[Verbatim[HoldPattern][lhs_], rhs_]} 
  :> {HoldForm[lhs], HoldForm[rhs]})
```

with `StringForm`

```
  StringForm[" `1` = `2` \n `3` = `4`\n`5` = `6`", 
  Sequence @@ Sequence @@@ prntHF[{a, b, az}]]
```

to get

[image]

Of course, another version

```
  SetAttributes[prntHF2, {HoldAll, Listable}];
  prntHF2[sym_] := (OwnValues[sym] /. 
  {RuleDelayed[Verbatim[HoldPattern][lhs_], rhs_]} :> 
  Row[{HoldForm[lhs], " = ", HoldForm[rhs]}])
```

would be much easier to use:

```
  Column[prntHF2[{a, b, az}]]
```

Comment: `HoldForm` is a very useful trick for this sort of thing. I'm surprised my own answer didn't include it :) +1

Comment: +1 This reminded me why I hate the _controlstrings_ of StringForm[]

Comment: @Andy, thank you for the vote. Actually, I was just thinking about `OwnValues` the same way :)

Comment: mmm does not work if you set az=1

Comment: @belisarius, me too:) One those things that I need to check docs every time I use it.

Comment: @Kguler, can you please say some words on why to use `OwnValues` and not simply: `Attributes[prntHF2] = {HoldAll, Listable};
prntHF2[sym_Symbol] := Row@{HoldForm@sym, " = ", sym}`?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, you need to keep both the symbol and the rhs unevaluated (pls see belisarius's comment). For the form you suggest `prntHF2[a]` gives `2` (rhs is evaluated) when `az=1`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I missed the part on holding the rhs as well, sorry.

Comment: Ok. So +1 again.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.  I'm doubtful that it is very robust though.

```
SetAttributes[printVar, {HoldAll, Listable}]

printVar[a_] := Row[{Defer[a], " = ", OwnValues[a][[1, 2]]}]
```

For example...

```
Column[printVar[{a,b}]]

==> a = 1 + az
    b =  5 + bz
```

**Edit:**

Due to @belisarius' comment regarding setting `az` to some value.

```
printVar[a_] := 
 Row[{Defer[a], " = ", 
   OwnValues[a] /. {RuleDelayed[_, expr_]} :> HoldForm[expr]}]
```

Which is admittedly sort of ugly.